# Posting Data through JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, api

I am trying to invoke an api through JQuery Ajax

Below is my code

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.ServerName.com/enquiry/report?recordStr=MFEF,1,BP03089999_USER,India@12,,6646,40,8,PMFI,Ruben,Damion,Pitts,Ruben,VTR0400108,,PANPN1010C,9201740108,ELECTRICITY BILL,EXBL0108,JOB CARD,JOBC010,OTHER ID,OTID0108,P03,8500176108,,,21121969,M,,,,,,C,Pitts Nivasthan,,MH,400108,Damion,K01,Damion,K01,Selene,K02,,,,,Damion,K01,,,,,ES',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(d) {
                $("#response").text("Success");
            },
            error: function(e) {
                $("#response").text("Error please try again");
            }
        });
```

The base address of api is

```
http://www.ServerName.com/enquiry/report
```

and the input is a long string

```
MFEF,1,BP03089999_USER,India@12,,6646,40,8,PMFI,Ruben,Damion,Pitts,Ruben,VTR0400108,,PANPN1010C,9201740108,ELECTRICITY BILL,EXBL0108,JOB CARD,JOBC010,OTHER ID,OTID0108,P03,8500176108,,,21121969,M,,,,,,C,Pitts Nivasthan,,MH,400108,Damion,K01,Damion,K01,Selene,K02,,,,,Damion,K01,,,,,ES
```

The API will receive it in parameter named `recordStr`

Now I am facing two issues:

1. How to send the parameter using data attribute in ajax call?

I tried the code below but it does not work

```
var recordStr = "MFEF,1,BP03089999_CIBILBANKUSER,India@123,,6646,40,8,CIBIL MFI,Ruben,Damion,Pitts,Ruben,VTR0400108,,PANPN1010C,9201740108,ELECTRICITY BILL,EXBL0108,JOB CARD,JOBC010,OTHER ID,OTID0108,P03,8500176108,,,21121969,M,,,,,,C,Pitts Nivasthan,,MH,400108,Damion,K01,Damion,K01,Selene,K02,,,,,Damion,K01,,,,,ES"

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.cibilhawk.com/MFI/enquiry/comboreport/,
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: recordStr,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(d) {
                $("#response").text("Success");
            },
            error: function(e) {
                $("#response").text("Error please try again");
            }
        });
```

2. This api works in Postman and returns data in XML format but in the browser it gives an error `Failed to load API , Response for preflight is invalid (redirect). Status Code: 307 Temporary Redirect`

How can I solve these two issues?

Comment: The preflight error would imply that you're going to encounter CORS issues. Does the first request work at all? Note that the second one is missing a `'` after the URL

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , I tried Edwin suggestion and problem 1 resolved but still getting 302 : Temporary Redirect

Comment: Do you want to send the data like as it is ? Like `MFEF,1,BP03089999_CIBILBANKUSER,India@123,,6646,...`

Comment: @DeepakM , this issue is resolved as per suggestion by Edwin , now I am facing Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your recordstring into a JSON object like below. That should do the trick.

```
// create a JSON object, instead of string
var recordStr = {'recordStr':"MFEF,1,BP03089999_CIBILBANKUSER,India@123,,6646,40,8,CIBIL MFI,Ruben,Damion,Pitts,Ruben,VTR0400108,,PANPN1010C,9201740108,ELECTRICITY BILL,EXBL0108,JOB CARD,JOBC010,OTHER ID,OTID0108,P03,8500176108,,,21121969,M,,,,,,C,Pitts Nivasthan,,MH,400108,Damion,K01,Damion,K01,Selene,K02,,,,,Damion,K01,,,,,ES"}

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.cibilhawk.com/MFI/enquiry/comboreport/,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: recordStr,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(d) {
            $("#response").text("Success");
        },
        error: function(e) {
            $("#response").text("Error please try again");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes , Problem 1 resolved but still showing status 302 : Temporary Redirect

Comment: Could be a like a CORS issue, or maybe it doesn't allow POST access? Did you try with switching the AJAX request to GET? `method:'GET'` or just remove as that would then use the default of GET method